# Translation of java commands in Linux systems

Tags: java, linux, executable-jar, translate, suse

I am currently using a linux system to execute a specific command that translates into another java command (java - jar)

For example:
when i try execute `/usr/bin/a` in terminal, it will read the `/usr/bin/a` command and translates into `'java -jar'` command

**I do not want to execute 'java -jar' command directly and i would to specify a full path in executing the command so is there a possible way to achieve this without using a script like /.sh?**

Things that i have attempted: 
i have tried using the alias command in bashrc files
for example in bashrc file:
`alias /usr/bin/a='java - jar'`

but when i try to source the bashrc files, it gives me an invalid alias.

I know i can use a /.sh script to execute the command but that is not my intention to do it.

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried to write a bash script with java -jar  and execute it ?

You test.sh file will contain:

```
java -jar test.jar
```

And after that you can run

```
./test.sh
```

And offcourse you can put to bin directory or create an alias for that bash file

Comment: Can you make your answer a bit more step wise so that @user1771844 can execute the steps.

Comment: If using a bash script, this command would be easy to do but i do not wish to use a bash script to achieve this. Thanks.